How is it that investment from January 2008 broke even by end of 2010?
According to this website, if I invested in January 2008, I would see a measly loss of 1.38% by the end of 2010.
https://www.officialdata.org/us/stocks/s-p-500/2008?amount=100&endYear=2010
But when I look at the S&P500 chart from that period, I see a drop of about 12%.

What explains the difference? It isn't deflation. Reinvesting dividends doesn't seem to be enough to make up for the difference either. I don't understand the math behind the returns on the webpage.

The site you linked to in your question:  https://www.officialdata.org/us/stocks/s-p-500/2008?amount=100&endYear=2010
has the following key information:

Change in price           -18.51% -9.73% / yr
Change incl. dividends  -0.12%  -0.04% / yr
Change incl. dividends, inflation-adjusted    -1.38% -0.46% / yr


but you dismiss it with the comment:

It isn't deflation. Reinvesting dividends doesn't seem to be enough to
make up for the difference either.

When you are invested in the market, dividends have to be included when evaluating your investment. The number of shares you owned was not constant during that three year period.
The site also mentions:

Remember, returns are based on the average closing price across the
entire month. Some losses are offset by dividend returns.

That can also have an impact on the calculations.

Taking this a step further, this also shows the power of dividends and dollar cost averaging.

Oh wow, I didn't read that table on the right. So it is about the dividend reinvestment after all. It's surprising how much dividends reinvestment can earn. I am glad I've been doing that with my portfolio. :)

Why are there two numbers Change in price -18.51% -9.73% / yr? What does each of them mean? When I do the calculation across more years, there are still two numbers presented.

Also, for those interested. Dividend reinvesting has a major long term impact. See this chart: https://schwab.bynder.com/m/3f78f85e31636943/original/Q23-Onward-Big-Picture.pdf

Your website uses Robert Shiller's economic data (available here).  That data includes an average monthly price so right away you can't compare it to anything else (eg, On January 2, 2008, the opening price of the S&P 500 index was $1,467.97 but your website starts at $1,378.76).  The dividend data is also tweaked:

Monthly dividend and earnings data are computed from the S&P four-quarter totals for the quarters since 1926, with linear interpolation to monthly figures

The December dividend does reflect the actual total dividend for the year but the other months are nonsense.
So that website will never match up with any chart based on real data.

Thank you, Kevin! This is the suspicion I had at the end of the day yesterday - that the data used on the linked website isn't accurate; it's rather an estimate.
